# MacOS Product Name Bundle Identifier Problem during application testing

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, bundle-identifier

I have a problem when trying to test an application on macOS. For reference, this was created in Unity.

The BundleID has been changed as a previous developer had used a very odd naming format, codesign and notarization works on the new app.

However, when I try to run the app it starts complaining about the app being purchased on another computer (which is correct, we still use the old version for testing) but it has been removed on this device and hidden in the App Store.

Anyone know anything else I can try to get past the problem of macOS knowing about the old app version.

If you log in it then just says the app is corrupt as I am guessing it is comparing it to the downloaded App Store version.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself, apologies for taking up bandwidth. In Unity untick Mac App Store Validation in Player Settings-> Other Settings